# Check if XML nodes are empty in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, nodes

Hi I am new to XML manipulation, my question would be if there is a possibility of detecting if the XML node is an empty node like this: `<gen:nodeName />`

I am able to manipulate single nodes however I would be interested if there is an approach like a loop or recursive function that could save some time doing manual labor looking trough every single node. I have no idea how to approach this problem though.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the dialect of SQL (`[sql]` is not enough, please specify always the RDBMS incl. version).

This is for SQL-Server, but the semantics should be the same.

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
    <SelfClosing />
    <NoContent></NoContent>
    <BlankContent> </BlankContent>
    <HasContent>blah</HasContent>
    <HasContent>other</HasContent>
</root>';

SELECT @xml.query(N'/root/*') AS AnyBelowRoor                  --All elements
      ,@xml.query(N'/root/*[text()]') AS AnyWithTextNode       --blah and other
      ,@xml.query(N'/root/*[not(text())]') AS NoText           --no text
      ,@xml.query(N'/root/*[text()="blah"]') AS AnyWithTextNode--blah only
```

The `<SelfClosing />` is semantically the same as the `<NoContent><NoContent>`. There is no difference.

It might be a surprise, but a `blank` as content is taken as empty too.

So the check for *empty or not empty* is the check for the existance of a `text()` node. one can negate this with `not()` to find all without a `text()`.

Interesting: The result for `NoText` comes back as this (SQL-Server)

```
<SelfClosing />
<NoContent />
<BlankContent />
```

The three elements are implicitly returned in the shortest format.

Comment: I didnt specify how my XML looks.. If I have multiple nodes with multiple parents and childs. How would I approach that problem then. Do i need to drill down to my root nodes individually in my @xml.query ? isn't there a less repetitive approach like a loop or something. Because if I have 20 root tags do I need to check everyone of them individually?

Comment: @whiterabbitj Use the edit option and place XML within your question. But you must mark it as code (Back Ticks or indentation with Ctrl+k)